# Where does bitbucket server store the repository?

Tags: git, windows-server-2012, bitbucket-server

**Background:**

Some time ago my company decided to host our own Atlassian products and we have our source code on a Bitbucket server that we host ourselves. Now our VM (Windows Server 2012) is falling apart and we can't reach bitbucket from the outside.

As noone has developed on our product for a little while we are not sure if we the code that we have locally is up to date or not.

**Problem:**

We need to get the latest version of our source code even though we can't get bitbucket server up and running.

I have connected to the server using remote desktop but can't seem to find the files.

**Question**

What is the default location of the GIT repo?
Is there a folder, other than "git" that I can search for that should get me to the right place?

**BTW**

We are moving to a hosted service...

All the best
/Taher

Comment: How many people have a local copy of the repository?  You could publish that as the canonical source of truth until you can find the repo on this server.

Comment: One person has an old copy that contains the a feature branch that probably is branched from the latest master. We will use that in case we can't get ahold of the entire repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this doc which will describe where the content is stored.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/bitbucket-server-home-directory-776640890.html

> The Bitbucket home directory is where your Bitbucket Server data is stored.

The git content is stored in the `data` folder. Each repository gest and id and the data of each one is stored in this id folder. Each folder contains bare repository is a *`bare`* repository so you will no be able to view the content.

Once you gain access to the course you have to store it somewhere else and then clone it in order to be able to view the content.

Answer (score 19):

Full disclosure: I work for Atlassian and was a Premier Support Engineer for Bitbucket Server / Bitbucket Data Center for two years. That out of the way, let's get down to it:

### Locating your repository

Bitbucket Server repositories are stored on disk at `$BITBUCKET_HOME/shared/data/repositories/<id>`, where `<id>` is the repository ID as found in the **repository** table in your database. Let's say you had a repository with the slug "jira" and the project key "ATLAS". (The slug is the url safe name you see in your git clone url; the project key is the uppercase abbreviation for your project name.) In order to find the repository ID you could run the following database query:

```
SELECT repository.id, repository.name, project.project_key
  FROM repository
  JOIN project ON project.id = repository.project_id
 WHERE repository.slug = 'jira'
   AND project.project_key = 'ATLAS';
```

With the ID in hand, you can locate the repository folder from the path above.

If, for some reason, your database is not available, there's another way. Each repository contains a **repository-config** file which, amongst other things, contains the repository and project names.  Its contents *might* look something like this:

```
#>***********************************************
# THIS FILE IS MAINTAINED BY ATLASSIAN BITBUCKET
# IT CONTAINS NO USER-SERVICEABLE PARTS.
#>***********************************************
[bitbucket]
    hierarchy = 8597e1f873a45c2b9d3f
    project = ATLAS
    repository = jira
```

You could use any number of bash one-liners to find the repo you're interested in. Here's a simple one I've used before, that just searches on repository name:

```
find $BITBUCKET_HOME/shared/data/repositories -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type f -name repository-config -print0 | xargs -0 grep "repository = jira"
```

For Windows you could use `findstr` in combination with other Windows command line utilities to achieve a similar effect.

### Using the repository

Repositories in Bitbucket Server are stored as bare repositories. Before going further it's important to understand the difference:

- "Normal" non-bare repositories are the kind you see when you clone a repo with `git clone <url>` or create a new repo with `git init`. This kind of repo stores all of the actual git repository data, with all the history, revisions, objects etc. inside a **.git** subfolder in your working directory. This kind of repository has a "work tree", which basically means it has all of the files from whatever branch you are working on "checked out" and available inside your working directory. Run `ls .git` in a repo on your local machine and you'll see what the inside of a git repo looks like.
- Bare repositories have no work tree, and no checked out files. What you would normally see inside a **.git** folder exists at the top level of a bare repo. `ls` inside any of the  folders under `$BITBUCKET_HOME/shared/data/repositories` and you'll see the same kinds of files / folders you saw in your local repo's **.git** folder.

The reason Bitbucket stores repos as "bare" is simple: no development work is being done server-side, so there's no need to ever "check out" a particular branch or work tree to do work on.

Now, it's very, very dangerous to try and perform any actions on a bare repository in Bitbucket Server. You're bypassing the entire server mechanism, all of its internal business logic, and you're liable to break things if you try. Best case scenario you could introduce changes that are not accounted for in Bitbucket's database and create inconsistencies that will be a lot of work to recover from.

What you want to do is the same thing you would always do: clone it! The great thing about git is that it's so flexible. You can git clone from a file path just as well as you can from a URL. Find a way to access your bare repository from a workstation directly, either by mounting the disk remotely, or simply by copying the relevant `<id>` repo folder to your local machine. Then clone it! `git clone $BITBUCKET_HOME/shared/data/repositories/<id> mylocalworkingcopy` will clone your bare repo into a new folder named *mylocalworkingcopy* and check out the default branch. You can do whatever you need to do here.

Warning: *don't* push your changes back. Pushing *will* work, but either you'll be pushing changes to a dummy copy, or you'll be pushing changes directly to the server, bypassing Bitbucket, and introducing commits, branches and objects that aren't being tracked by Bitbucket Server. This is the inconsistent state I was referring to above. It's something you can recover from, but it's a pain in the neck and best avoided.

Comment: Your answers seems to contain a lot of what looks like `linux` commands that don't appear to work for a question tagged `windows-server-2012`

Comment: @MickyD that's why I specifically called that out in my answer and provided some guidance for finding a Windows equivalent.

Comment: Thx, you saved my day. this answer was really helpful.

Comment: Oh man this post is so useful! Thanks for going to all that detail, I can't believe git clone sorted out the files and everything

Answer (score -4):

Bitbucket encrypts your repos they aren't available as files via browsing. Or well they are but not as actual files.

Comment: This is not true, Bitbucket does not "encrypt your repos". All repositories can be accessed directly on disk, they're just bare repos without a working tree.